# Installing scrapy (openSSL)

Tags: linux, centos, scrapy, pyopenssl

I'm using scrapy for couple of months now. I've been using it on the couple of machines and never had trouble with it. I used it on Windows xp and 7, I also used it on arch linux and never had trouble installing. Pretty much it was only pip install scrapy and done.

Now I'm trying to set it up on the production server that is using CentOS. As CentOS has python2.4 by default first I made parallel install of python2.7. Also I installed virtualenv for python 2.7 and at that point everything looked like it can't go wrong, I had my clean environment and had my pip.

But when I tried pip install scrapy it gave ma an error.

```
OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function 'ssl_Connection_set_context':

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:289: warning: implicit declaration of function'SSL_set_SSL_CTX'

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function 'ssl_Connection_get_servername':

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: 'TLSEXT_NAMETYPE_host_name' undeclared (first use in this function)

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:313: error: for each function it appears in.)

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:320: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SSL_get_servername'

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:320: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c: In function 'ssl_Connection_set_tlsext_host_name':

OpenSSL/ssl/connection.c:346: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SSL_set_tlsext_host_name'

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1
```

And this below is error that is kept in pip log file.

Running setup.py egg_info for package pyOpenSSL

```
running egg_info
writing pip-egg-info/pyOpenSSL.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/pyOpenSSL.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/pyOpenSSL.egg-info/dependency_link$
warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found
```

If someone has an idea what could it be, or had this problem please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be known bug for pyOpenSSL

https://bugs.launchpad.net/pyopenssl/+bug/845445

I solved with just manually installing 0.12 version

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL/0.12